# ¿Cómo filtrar las líneas con palabras que terminen en ".com"?

Tags: linux, grep

Tengo un archivo datos.txt que contiene estas líneas:

```
Marzo user1.com.pe 
Abril user2.com user3.gob
```

Quiero palabras que terminen unicamente en `.com` y he usado

```
cat datos.txt | grep "\.com\>"
```

pero no funciona bien porque me devuelve:

```
Marzo user1.com.pe 
Abril user2.com user3.gob
```

Cuando debería devolver solamente:

```
Abril user2.com user3.gob
```

¿Por qué aparece `user1.com.pe`?

Yo quiero únicamente palabras  que terminen en `.com`.

No deseo usar `grep -o`, quiero el grep normal con las líneas completas que cumplen el patrón.

El problema es que `\>` funciona cuando las palabras son puras letras `[a-zA-Z]` continuas, pero si hay un punto intermedio en la palabra el comando `\>` entiende el `.` como fin de palabra, como por ejemplo con "user.com.pe". Yo quiero ubicar las palabras que terminen todo ese bloque con ".com", donde obviamente "user.com.pe" quiero que se descarte.

Comment: ¿Quieres cada una de las palabras que terminen por ".com" o las líneas que terminen así? Es decir, ¿cuál sería la salida esperada? Entiendo que si solamente buscas palabras deberías usar `grep -o` y el resultado sería solamente "user2.com". Dale a [edit] para esclarecerlo, por favor.

Comment: Además, nótese que `cat fichero | grep '...'` se puede simplificar con `grep '...' fichero`.

Answer (score 2):

Luego de horas lo logré con esta:

```
$ cat datos.txt | grep -E "(\.com\s|\.com$)"
Abril user2.com user3.gob
```

Comment: Me alegra que lo solucionaras. Sin embargo, para ayudar a futuros users, puedes añadir la explicacion de por que esta  respuesta da solucion? Mira [answer] para mejroar tu respuesta. Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero es que tienes que usar `grep` con expresiones regulares, ya que le tienes que decir que quieres todos los que terminen en `.com`, seria algo así:

```
cat prueba.txt | grep -E '\.com$'
```

Aquí tienes una [herramienta para hacer expresiones regulares](http://regexr.com/). Ademas en la herramienta puedes pegar todo tu archivo y hacer las pruebas que quieras sin tener que estar ejecutando constantemente el comando. A la izquierda tienes una ayuda.

Ademas de eso, comprueba que el archivo o las lineas no tienen espacios en blanco, ya que eso invalida tu `regex`, puedes ver las terminaciones de linea (`$`) y los espacios con:

```
cat -A prueba.txt
```

Comment: La extensión `-E` no es necesaria si solamente estás poniendo un parámetro en la búsqueda. En cuanto a las herramientas, sí, funcionan, pero qué más fácil que pegarlo en la consola y lanzarlo desde allí :)

Answer (score 0):

Se puede utilizar `grep` con el parámetro `-P` para habilitar las expresiones regulares tipo PERL.

```
grep -P '\w\.com(\s|$)' datos.txt
```

La expresión regular `\w\.com(\s|$)` indica que se busca una palabra (cadena alfanumérica más guiones bajos) con `\w` seguida de `.com` (solo que escapamos el punto con `\.`), luego tiene que seguir o un "espacio" o un fin de linea; esto indicado con `(\s|$)`